# using express validator for validating password as middleware

Tags: node.js, middleware

```
 router.post('/signup', [
   body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req, res }) =>{
      if(value !== req.body.password) {
          console.log(value)
          console.log("passworss didnot match")
          return res.end("password and confirm password didinot match") // going to auth.signup controllel
         // throw  new Error ("passwords didnot match")

      }
  })
]
 ,auth.signUp);
```

The following code is not exiting when password is not matching   because body is not having res object so i decided to make it as midddleware and use it

```
let auth   = require('../controllerls/auth');
     router.post('/signup', validatePassword ,auth.signUp);
```

In the above piece of code  i am importing the my middleware code for checking

```
    const { check, validationResult,body } = require('express-validator');


    const vaiditePassword = (req,res,next) => {
      console.log("we are inside the validate password method")
console.log(req.body.email) // check to see whether i am having access to my req.body seems fine
    return  body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req }) =>{
      console.log(value)
        if(value !== req.body.password) {
            console.log("passworss didnot match")
            res.send("verfiy password and password didn't match");
        }
        next()
    })

}
module.exports = vaiditePassword
```

These my piece of code which i made into seprate file as middleware now i don't what is happening my request is stuck plese help me

**i want to use express-validator because i want to learn it, i know we get req.body.confirmpassword and req.body.password and check it**

Comment: Does it get stuck when u are having the matching passwords or otherwise?

Comment: Thanks 

for your interest  i can see the code execution upto  body.email     body('confirm password ').custom is not getting excuted

Comment: Oh I know what happen now.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

```
return  body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req }) =>{
    console.log(value)
    if(value !== req.body.password) {
        console.log("passworss didnot match")
        res.send("verfiy password and password didn't match");
    }
    next()
})
```

will return a function (you can call it middleware) hence nothing inside would get executed unless u specifically ask for that by adding a couple of brackets

```
return  body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req }) =>{
    console.log(value)
    if(value !== req.body.password) {
        console.log("passworss didnot match")
        res.send("verfiy password and password didn't match");
    }
    next()
})(req.body.confirmpassword, { req })
```

With that being said, it's an anti-pattern to use it as such. Please check the documentation more carefully for usage pattern, looks like they are expecting you to return values from within the callback, not using `res` object directly

Also, since you are creating a middleware yourself, why use `express-validator`, this can be as simple as

```
const vaiditePassword = (req,res,next) => {
    console.log("we are inside the validate password method")
    console.log(req.body.email) // check to see whether i am having access to my req.body seems fine
    if(req.body.confirmpassword !== req.body.password) {
            console.log("passworss didnot match")
            return res.send("verfiy password and password didn't match");
    }
    next()
}
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get can you please elaborate

Comment: basically add this `(req.body.confirmpassword, { req })` immediately after your `custom` function call

Comment: return  body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req }) =>{
      (req.body.confirmpassword, { req })
      console.log(value) still same issue if your ok i will provide you the github link

Comment: No no no not like that, I have added more details to the answer for your ease of visualisation

Comment: Thanks but sorry to bother you more  i am getting these error  TypeError: Cannot create property 'Symbol(express-validator#contexts)' on string '111'  111 is my confirm password

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?